# Duplicate check with wherein and groupBy getting slow - Laravel DB queries

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have written the below code using Laravel DB queries to get all the duplicates by checking multiple columns and update the status for duplicates to `1` and other to `0`. It's working correctly. But it takes a lot of time to update data. I have check around 1000 records and it takes more than 15min. How can I speed up this process?

```
        $duplicateList = DB::table('vehicles')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('auc_date', date("Y-m-d"))
                    ->orWhere('auc_date', date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+1 day')));
            })
            ->whereNull('deleted_at')
            ->select('id')
            ->whereIn(DB::raw('(`site`, `lot_number`,`chassis_id`)'), function ($query) {
                $query->select('site', 'lot_number', 'chassis_id')
                    ->from('vehicles')
                    ->groupBy('site', 'lot_number', 'auc_date', 'chassis_id')
                    ->having( DB::raw('COUNT(*)'), '>', 1);
            })
            ->get()
            ->pluck('id');

        DB::table('vehicles')
            ->whereIn('id', $duplicateList)
            ->update(['approve' => null, 'duplicate_entry' => 1]);

        DB::table('vehicles')
            ->whereNotIn('id', $duplicateList)
            ->update(['approve' => 1, 'duplicate_entry' => 0]);
```

Update: This is the genarated sql for first query

```
select  `id`
    from  `vehicles`
    where  (      `auc_date` = 2021-08-06
              or  `auc_date` = 2021-08-07
           )
      and  `deleted_at` is null
      and  (`site`, `lot_number`,`chassis_id`) in (
        SELECT  `site`, `lot_number`, `chassis_id`
            from  `vehicles`
            group by  `site`, `lot_number`, `auc_date`, `chassis_id`
            having  COUNT(*) > 1
           )
```

Comment: Are you sure, you want to have the same `where()` condition in both update queries?

Comment: Sorry, one is `WhereNotIn` I will update the code.

Comment: Your `>whereIn(DB::raw...` line looks weird. What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: You could probably do everything in one query but you'd have to use `CASE` statement in update query then.

Comment: @shaedrich I want to check duplicates for `site`, `lot_number`,`chassis_id` all these three columns values.

Comment: @shaedrich I also try `dd` for `$duplicateList` variable without updating anything. I also very slow.

Comment: Could you get the query as string, prefix it with `EXPLAIN` and run it on your database? Maybe you're missing an index or the like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235665/discussion-between-udara-and-shaedrich).

Comment: I have opened a chat room, can you please help me?

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: @RickJames generated SQL added to my question

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a date:  `2021-08-07`; this is:  `"2021-08-07"`.

Two problems with

```
 and  (`site`, `lot_number`,`chassis_id`)
         in ( SELECT ... )
```

- "Row constructors" are (or at least used to be) very inefficient and not optimizable.
- `IN (SELECT ...)` is (or at least used to be) very inefficient and not optimizable.

Turn the `IN` into a `JOIN` and add this composite index:

```
INDEX(`site`, `lot_number`, `chassis_id`)
```

This is strange looking:

```
        SELECT        `site`, `lot_number`,             `chassis_id`
            from  `vehicles`
            group by  `site`, `lot_number`, `auc_date`, `chassis_id`
            having  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Perhaps you mean

```
        SELECT        `site`, `lot_number`, `chassis_id`
            from  `vehicles`
            group by  `site`, `lot_number`, `chassis_id`
            having  COUNT(DISTINCT auc_date) > 1
```

Overall:

```
SELECT id
    FROM ( SELECT      site`, `lot_number`, `chassis_id`
            from  `vehicles`
            group by  `site`, `lot_number`, `chassis_id`
            having  COUNT(DISTINCT auc_date) > 1
         ) x
    JOIN vehicles  USING()
    where  `auc_date` IN ( "2021-08-06", "2021-08-07" )
      and  `deleted_at` is null
```

What happens after you get a list of `id`?  That is, should you combine this query with whatever happens next?

(I do not know how, or even if, this can be turned back into Laravel code.  It is unfortunate, but using a 3rd party package to interface with MySQL means that you need to understand *both*.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check and let you know.